# How to split the comma separated values in tcl

Tags: csv, tcl

I have several lines separated by comma in a file, I want to add the comma separated values into a list. How can I do it? Split command gives me a list. But I want to maintain array for hold these values.

```
            For example : Jack,John,Ted
```

I want to create an array to hold these values. How can I do this?

Comment: If it really is CSV data, consider using the [csv package](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/csv.html) in tcllib. It handles a whole bunch of tricky edge cases for you that `split` doesn't.

Comment: yes, csv's formats are more robust and have double quoted entries since you can have a comma in one of the entries - eg "Smith,Jack","John","Ted", ....etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely a Tcl list is actually the correct data structure for your needs.  A common misunderstanding with Tcl is that its `list` data structure is like a traditional linked list data structure, with all the implications thereof (such as O(n) access time).  In fact, the Tcl `list` is really a vector, with O(1) access to elements, as well as efficient enumeration via the `foreach` command.  In comparison, Tcl's `array` is actually a hash table, which may be what you want -- but if all you need is to iterate through the elements, or access specific elements efficiently, a Tcl `list` is perfect.

To iterate through the elements, use `foreach`, as mentioned:

```
foreach name $values {
    puts $name
}
```

To access a specific element, use `lindex`.  Remember that lists are 0-indexed, so index 2 is the third element in the list:

```
puts [lindex $values 2]
```